# Is there a problem in having same product with different names in different pages?

Tags: microdata, schema.org

When it comes to structured data, schema.org for products, is there a problem in having the same product with 2 different names in 2 different pages for layout reasons?

Example: Category page with many products. Objects appear in smaller divs that don't fit complete name vs product page totally dedicated to one product that fits all the information.

**Category Page:**

```html
<span itemprop="name">Dell 30" Monitor</span>
```

**Product Page:**

```html
<span itemprop="name">Dell UltraSharp 30" LCD Monitor</span>
```

Comment: Did you set the url property that all `Thing`'s have?

Comment: @Brendon If you mean itemprop="url", yes I have

Comment: In that case, I don't think there would be a problem, since you have tied the two products together. I couldn't be certain though wrt SEO, etc.

Comment: Can you put the full product name in the DIV, but truncate it with CSS or Javascript to make it fit. That would solve both your problems. I suspect that Google would be unsure of which name to use, because they're getting conflicting information.

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht Technically, yes, but I'd like to refrain from doing that.

Comment: @guisasso have you seen any examples in the wild of product meta data being used on category pages? I remember thinking about doing that about a year ago, but I can swear I came across a reason why it was a bad idea. Sorry that I can't remember my source.

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht I have, but nothing that made me think not to do it. I'll definitely research it a bit more. Thanks

Comment: You could also put the long text in a div of class 'long' and the short text in a div of class 'short' and css either one of them as hidden depending on context. SEO then, would have both versions of the name for both pages.

Comment: @Octopus That's a good idea, but I'm afraid it could bring problems. I do have a legit reason for doing so, but it just seems sketchy to use structure data and hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Schema.org perspective, it’s fine. But how consumers handle it is a different matter.

If it’s only about *displaying* the shorter name, you could use a `meta` element to provide the actual/long product name:

```html
<span>Dell 30" Monitor</span>
<meta itemprop="name" content='Dell UltraSharp 30" LCD Monitor' />
```

You could even provide multiple `name` properties, if you think that’s useful (how consumers interpret this is, again, up to them):

```html
<span itemprop="name">Dell 30" Monitor</span>
<meta itemprop="name" content='Dell UltraSharp 30" LCD Monitor' />
```

Comment: Although that wasn't the question, your answer offers a great alternative and it is likely to be the route I'll be following. Thanks.