# Should Schema.org structured data for products be used on category pages on an e-commerce site?

Tags: seo, ecommerce, schema.org

I use schema.org structured data markup on all of my product pages. The products are well indexed in Google, and the meta data shows up mostly as expected.

My question is a sub-question to the question [Is there a problem in having same product with different names in different pages?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52468/is-there-a-problem-in-having-same-product-with-different-names-in-different-page). Should schema.org markup be used for products on category pages that list products?

I was personally under the opinion that structured data for an "item" should be used explicitly for the page that represents that product.

That said, I can also understand the idea that having other properly marked up data pointing to the same URI as the product as also being beneficial.

So, should products on listing pages be using scheme.org meta data, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually posted that question, and another: [Is it okay to have more than one Product (with image, description and SKU) per page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51934/structured-data-is-it-okay-to-have-more-than-one-image-description-and-sku-per)

As Dan has answered my question, it appears to be okay to do so. There's not a lot of documentation about it, but if you run the following code on [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) it displays all the data correctly, so apparently there's no issue.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<span itemprop="name">Test name 1</span>
<img src="test1.jpg" />
<span itemprop="description">Description test 1</span>
<span itemprop="sku">#001</span>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<span itemprop="name">Test name 2</span>
<img src="test2.jpg" />
<span itemprop="description">Description test 2</span>
<span itemprop="sku">#002</span>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<span itemprop="name">Test name 3</span>
<img src="test3.jpg" />
<span itemprop="description">Description test 3</span>
<span itemprop="sku">#003</span>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: Yes. It used to be "not supported" but Google changed how they feel now: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies

> A category page listing several different products (or recipes,
>   videos, or any other type). Each entity should be marked up using the
>   relevant schema.org type, such as schema.org/Product for product
>   category pages. Marking up just one category entity from all listed on
>   the page is against our guidelines.

It validates as a list of product entities, <del>[but the "official" Google doc says](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750?hl=en)</del>:

> <del>Product markup on listing or category pages is not supported.</del>

<del>This doesn't mean that it won't work though. As we know what Google says is not what Google does. It doesn't hurt to have the multi-product markup in there regardless. It's not like they will de-rank your site for including support for something like that.</del>

Comment: **UPD**: this very document is now saying *Use markup for a specific product, not a category or list of products. For example, "shoes in our shop" is not a specific product. Currently, product rich results only support pages that focus on a single product. We recommend focusing on adding markup to product pages instead of pages that list products or a category of products.*